# What is the best way to handle the Angular material reactive form error messages?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

In our project we are using Angular material forms. Coming to the validation

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
    <input matInput [formControl]="emailFormControl" 
           placeholder="Ex. pat@example.com">
    <mat-hint>Errors appear instantly!</mat-hint>
    <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('email') && !emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
      Please enter a valid email address
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
      Email is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Angular material    component defaully it self checking that field is touched/ submitted validation states. and applying invalid red color to the field and error message.
No need to do anything.

Generally documentaion suggest above approach. But instead of wirte error message directly in html and to reduce number of lines 
we are passing that though service like this. But this is not a best practice that calling a function or service directly from html.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="emailFormControl" 
           placeholder="Ex. pat@example.com">

    <mat-error>
      <span [innerHTML]="commonService.getErrorMessages('emailFormControl',exampleForm )"></span>
        <br>
        <span [innerHTML]="getErrorMessages('emailFormControl',exampleForm )"></span>

    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

I know Calling a function in html thought component or service to bind data is impact the performence according to the change detection.

Check the following link for reference [Example material reactive form](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dudnhb?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.html)

So What is alternate and best approach?

Comment: you can write a function in your component that has all the logic for returning various errors and use the value returned by it in your template.

Comment: but every component we need to write , ie I wrote it on common service, ours is very big project

Comment: Considering you have only 1 line less for a less explicit content, i'm not sure it's a win approach. But if you choose it, i would advice you to use a custom pipe rather than a function : functions into a template trigger the change detection way more than needed and might impact the performance.

Comment: yes it's impact the performence. Can you please provide any example what exactly you are saying

Answer (score -1):

`mat-error` elements are managed by `MatFormField` so they don't need to be explicitly shown/hidden unless you have more than one. On top of that, errors are always triggered by a change of some sort, so you can subscribe to status and value changes on form objects and set error messages as needed, using only one `mat-error`. For example:

```
<mat-error>{{emailErrorMsg}}</mat-error>
...
emailErrorMsg: string = '';
...

ngOnInit() {
  ...
  this.exampleForm.statusChanges.subscribe(() => this.setErrors());
}

setErrors() {
  if (exampleForm.controls['emailFormControl'].hasError('required')) {
    this.emailErrorMsg = "Email is required";
  }
  else if (exampleForm.controls['emailFormControl'].hasError('email')) {
    this.emailErrorMsg = "Please enter a valid email address";
  }
};
```

This works well except for "required" which can be triggered without any value or status change. In those cases, a `blur` listener can be used on the inputs:

```
<input (blur)="setErrors()">
```

Comment: If i have multiple fields then ?

Comment: You can subscribe to either the FormGroup or to FormControl objects - whatever you prefer. Use multiple error variables for multiple fields.

Comment: Ok. But I  think it's not a good practice to put multiple variable. If my future form may contain more fields. And i am looking for common functionality for all components

Comment: It is good practice to use as many variables as you need to implement your application efficiently and successfully, and no more. My example can be used as common functionality.